# how to pass a label value with the querysting

Tags: asp.net, label

I would like to send a label value whith the querystring. How do I do that?

```
<asp:Label ID="lblForward" runat="server" Text="0" Visible="false"></asp:Label>

<a href="../Product/?ProductID=<%#Eval("ProductID") %>&BrandID=<%#Eval("BrandID") %>&Sizes=<%#Eval("lblForward.Text") %>">GO</a>
```

this lblForward.Text is the value that I want to pass whith the Querysting. Its always 0 or 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<%#...%>` is only applicable to data binding contexts. You can try

```
<%= lblForward.Text %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either this

```
<a href='../Product/?ProductID=<%#Eval("ProductID") %>&BrandID=<%#Eval("BrandID") %>&Sizes=<%="lblForward.Text"%>'>GO</a>
```

Or you can create the url from server side and set it to the A href, but make sure A href also requires a `RUNAT="Server"` attribute